# Where can I find high-resolution images of these Sumerian tablets

Tags: ancient-history, book

I've looked around quite a bit and couldn't find them. Looking for sketches, and a bonus images of the tablets, of the following Sumerian documents:

- Kesh temple hymn (maybe that is in [here](http://www.etana.org/sites/default/files/coretexts/14911.pdf), not sure)
- Enheduanna Hymns
- Debate between Bird and Fish

For example, I see sketches of the Enheduanna Hymns [here](https://www.atanet.org/publications/beacons_10_pages/page_15.pdf), but they are a bit too low quality, and I would like to find the primary source if possible, like the site/place that has the original document about it. Also would be nice to see the tablets. Looking for these things for the above documents, which don't seem to be found [here](http://etana.org/coretexts/search?keyword=Cuneiform&subject=&title=&creator=&format=All). All of the other wikipedia stuff on the [ancient Sumerian documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_literature) can be found at etana.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version of the Kesh Temple Hymn, from the collection of the Walters Art Museum, Baltimore, Maryland, has been included in the [Cuneiform Digital Library Initiative](https://cdli.ucla.edu/) (CDLI). The CDLI reference number is P272905 and the full details are on the [archival page](https://cdli.ucla.edu/search/archival_view.php?ObjectID=P272905) (click on the image on that page for a high-resolution (4050 x 4150 pixel) version).

[image: Kesh Temple Hymn]

Further cuneiform sources for the Kesh Temple Hymn can be found on the relevant [bibliography page](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section4/b4802.htm) on the The Electronic Text Corpus of Sumerian Literature (ETCSL) site.

---

Similarly, lists of cuneiform sources can be found on the appropriate ETCSL pages for the  [Sumerian Temple Hymns](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section4/b4801.htm) (I'm assuming this is what you meant by 'Enheduanna Hymns') and [The debate between Bird and Fish](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=c.5.3.5&display=Crit&charenc=gcirc#).

---

Please be aware that many of these tables are fragmentary, and not especially photogenic. As such, you may not find good, high-resolution images online.